# Facebook Contact Importer using PHP

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth, import-contacts

I recently developed contacts importer for Gmail and Yahoo. However, I come to know that Twitter doesnt give any contacts(email) using oAuth. So, I wanna know whether Facebook allows to import the contacts of friends or not.

If yes, Do they use oAuth or any other authentication method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook will not give you friends email addresses via the API.

Comment: But I have seen direct contact imports from facebook to yahoo mail. I did it today only

Comment: Can i get access by taking username and password of users. ALthough it will be not as friendly as oAUTH authenticaton , still can I go for that ???

Comment: Facebook and Yahoo have a special deal in place to allow that.  Its not available to anyone else.  It is against Facebook's terms of service to ask them for their password directly and/or scrape their website.